# Attribute Routing with Multiple Leading Zero Decimals

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Current ActionResult:

```
[Route("EvaluatorSetup/{evalYear}/{department}")]
public ActionResult RoutedEvaluatorSetup(int evalYear, string department)
{
    return EvaluatorSetup((int?)evalYear, department);
}
```

I would like to use the url:

```
/EvaluatorSetup/2014/001.3244
```

where the {department} is a ultimately a string, however, the routing is not picking up {department} as a string.

A. I don't know what type MVC is expecting for "001.3244", or what it is picking it up as.

B. I want to maintain it as a string with optional leading zeros, as in the example.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

What I mean is, when I put a break in my code at the return line, it never fires.

```
/EvaluatorSetup/2014/foobar (WORKS!)

/EvaluatorSetup/2014/001.3244 (DOESN'T WORK!)
```

This leads me to believe that my routing is not correct:

```
[Route("EvaluatorSetup/{evalYear}/{department}")]
```

Specifically, it doesn't seem that 001.3244 is a valid string.  So my question is how do I correct this:

```
[Route("EvaluatorSetup/{evalYear}/{department}")]
public ActionResult RoutedEvaluatorSetup(int evalYear, string department)
```

so that I can enter a uri:

```
/EvaluatorSetup/2014/001.3244
```

preferably where the leading zeros are maintained.

I thought about something like this:

```
[Route("EvaluatorSetup/{evalYear}/{corporation}.{department}")]
```

however, that is a guess.  I don't even know if that is valid.

**Additional Update:**

the old route in the RouteConfig.cs (which doesn't seem to work anymore) is this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "evaluations_evaluatorsetupget",
    "evaluations/evaluatorsetup/{evalyear}/{department}",
    new { controller = "evaluations", action = "evaluatorsetup", evalyear = @"^(\d{4})$", department = @"^(\d{3}\.\d{4})$" },
    new { evalyear = @"^(\d{4})$", department = @"^(\d{3}\.\d{4})$" }
    );
```

Comment: Don't know, what does `EvaluatorSetup` do?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `.` that's messing up the route?

Comment: No... I'm not sure.  As I said... that was just a guess... I'm outside my knowledge at that point.

Comment: See if `/EvaluatorSetup/2014/0013244` works. If it does, you know it's the `.`.

Comment: Indeed.  It DOES fire without the "."

... Any thoughts on how to get the routing to fire with the "."?

Comment: Or am I just talking crazy now...?

Comment: I'll post an answer...

Comment: You will have to encode the `.` then, so your url will become `/EvaluatorSetup/2014/001%2E3244`. If you are generating the url through `UrlHelper`, it should encode it for you automatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is the `.` in the URL.

By default, if a `.` is present the `StaticFileHandler` handles the request and looks for a filename matching the path on the file system. To override this behavior, you can assign a handler to a URL you are trying to use. For example, adding the following to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" path="/EvaluatorSetup/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

will force any request starting with `/EvaluatorSetup/` to use the `UrlRoutingHandler` (the handler associated with MVC routes).

** Solution Supplement **

I found that this solution worked when I ALSO added the following to the httpRuntime element in web.config:

```
<system.web> 
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Hmm... Haven't gotten this to work yet.  Trying various permutations.

Comment: This got me in the right direction.  I've submitted an edit to the answer that got me the right routing.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[Route("EvaluatorSetup/{evalYear}/{department:string}")]
```

I believe the default is `int`.

Comment: This didn't quite work.  It appears that the "." is messing with the route.