# MVC Catch all with file names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a controller action that functions like a virtual directory that I use to show contents of a physical folder.

So, when you go to `/Document/Folder/anyFolder/name/here` it will show data from `C:\BaseFolder\anyFolder\name\here`.

However, when trying to route to a file with an extension, ASP.NET will try to find a file in `C:\MySiteFolder\anyFolder\name\here\filename.txt`, which will fail because that folder doesn't exist, it exists in `C:\BaseFolder` instead, so I get a 404 instead of the controller catching the request.

Here is my current route for `Document/Folder`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Document Folder", "Document/Folder/{*folderPath}", new { controller = "Document", action = "Folder" });
```

And my default controller routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I thought that the `{*folderPath}` parameter would catch all, but it doesn't catch file names (i.e. things with extensions). How can I have the catch-all parameter `{*folderPath}` also catch files names? Or should I try to add an `IgnoreRoute` for paths with `.`s in it?

I tried this, but this failed:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Document/Folder/{*path}.{extension}");
```

Error

```
A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303304/attribute-routing-with-multiple-leading-zero-decimals/27303780#27303780).

Comment: that worked like a charm! Thanks! So it will only assign this `UrlRoutingHandler` when it's in the specified `path`, I assume, perfect!