# MVC catch-all route is not being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

currently I am developing a website with MVC5 where I need to serve some images from outside of the project folder. An example url for an img-src would be:

```
<img src="/Image/sub1/sub2/imgname.jpg" />
```

My idea now is, that i could use a catch-all route. So I created the following route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Image",
            url: "Image/{*subpath}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And the corresponding controller:

```
public class TestController : BaseController {
    public ActionResult Index(string subpath) {
        var path = Path.Combine(ImageFolderPath, subpath);

        return new FileStreamResult(
            new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg"
        );
    }
}
```

My problem now is, that the controller or one of its methods is not being called. FireBug always tells me, that a 404 is being returned for the image.

I also tried MVC5 attribute routing:

```
// in RouteConfig.cs
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

// controller
[Route("image/{*subpath}")]
public class TestController : BaseController {
    public ActionResult Index(string subpath) {
        var path = Path.Combine(ImageFolderPath, subpath);

        return new FileStreamResult(
            new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg"
        );
    }
}
```

But the result remains the same. My index method is never being called. I would be really thankful for any hint on what I am probably missing or did wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you just type your path in the url? Does it show the .jpg image?

Answer (score 1):

I now found the reason, why my controller was not being called. If the request url contains a '.', the static file handler will try to handle the request.

A workaround can be found here: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303304/attribute-routing-with-multiple-leading-zero-decimals/27303780#27303780)